# Integral on a polyhedral non-rectangular domain with Python

Tags: python, integral

You are a Python user and you want to evaluate this triple integral:

[image]

for a certain function `f`, say `f(x,y,z) = x + y*z`.

In R, a possibility is to nest one-dimensional integrals:

```r
f <- function(x,y,z) x + y*z

integrate(Vectorize(function(x) { 
  integrate(Vectorize(function(y) { 
    integrate(function(z) { 
      f(x, y, z) 
    }, -10, 6 - x - y)$value
   }), -5, 3 - x)$value 
}), -5, 4) 
## -5358.3 with absolute error < 9.5e-11
```

The point I don't like with this method is that it does not take into account
the error estimates on the first two integrals.

I'm interested in the Python way to realize this method.
But I'm also interested in a Python way to get a result with a more reliable error estimate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To give a solution to this problem, we will use four libraries:

```py
import numpy as np
import pypoman
from scipy.spatial import Delaunay
from pysimplicialcubature.simplicialcubature import integrateOnSimplex
```

The domain of integration is defined by the set of inequalities:

[image]

which is equivalent to:

[image]

This set of inequalities defines a convex polyhedron.
We can get the vertices of this polyhedron with the **pypoman** package (or
we could use **pycddlib** but this would be more lengthy):

```py
A = np.array([
  [-1, 0, 0], # -x
  [ 1, 0, 0], # x
  [ 0,-1, 0], # -y
  [ 1, 1, 0], # x+y
  [ 0, 0,-1], # -z
  [ 1, 1, 1]  # x+y+z
])
b = np.array([5, 4, 5, 3, 10, 6])

vertices = pypoman.compute_polytope_vertices(A, b)
```

Now that we get the vertices of this convex polytope, we decompose it into
tetrahedra with the help of the Delaunay algorithm:

```py
dlnay = Delaunay(vertices)
tetrahedra = np.asarray(vertices)[dlnay.simplices]
```

A tetrahedron is a three-dimensional simplex. So it remains to apply the
**pysimplicialcubature** library to evaluate the integral:

```py
# function to integrate
f = lambda x : x[0] + x[1] * x[2]
# integral of f on the tetrahedra
I_f = integrateOnSimplex(f, tetrahedra)
print(I_f)
```

We get:

```
{
 'integral': -5358.300000000005, 
 'estAbsError': 1.1879700000000003e-08, 
 'functionEvaluations': 330.0, 
 'returnCode': 0, 
 'message': 'OK'
}
```

Actually our function `f` is a multivariate polynomial. In this case, with
**pysimplicialcubature**, it is possible to get the exact value of the integral
(function `integratePolynomialOnSimplex`).

---

## Edit

This method is now implemented in the [PyPolyhedralCubature](https://github.com/stla/PyPolyhedralCubature) package.